# python boto cannot get environ variable of docker container

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker

I use the docker image
`jrei/systemd-ubuntu:18.04` 
installed golang and set up `github.com/remind101/assume-role`
and run `Django` over `uwsgi` with `nginx`

he Python version is **3.7** and **boto** version is **2.49.0**

Also ,Django requirements is install in **venv**.

After I set up the aws config file in the ~/.aws/config and credentials in ~/.aws/credentials

The server works fine, but the **boto** package can't get the environ variable

The Django Page show the error message:

```
NoAuthHandlerFound at /
No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: NoAuthHandlerFound
Exception Value:    
No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials
Exception Location: /opt/web/camelot-portal-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto/auth.py in get_auth_handler, line 1021
Python Executable:  /opt/web/camelot-portal-env/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.7.8
Python Path:    
['.',
 '',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/web/camelot-portal-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

I checked the `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

both not empty, and I try config the `$AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE`  twice ,to `~/.aws/config and`  `~/.aws/credentials`

both time I restart the uwsgi service , boto still not getting any key or key ID.

finally ,If I install the requirements and use`python manage.py runserver`  in my local environment,

the boto package can get the environment variable normally, and all works fine.

which part is the problem? the docker container? uwsgi? or venv? any idea?

Comment: Where are you running the docker? Is it on ECS?

Comment: In Docker you wouldn't generally use either systemd or a virtual environment.  (It's simpler to install packages into the "system" Python, and the Docker environment gives you isolation from other Python installations.)  Can you provide a [mcve] with at least your Dockerfile and a description of how you're running the image and how you're injecting the credentials?

Comment: i tried both on docker container and vm, all same problem. the problem is on uwsgi.

Answer (score 0):

---

#### 8/15 edited

I found the problem is on the uWSGI ,It doesn't get the linux env variable.Unless I set env in file like this:
envfile

```
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
```

and uwsgi file:

```
for-readline = /path/to/envfile
  env = %(_)
endfor =
```

then the python of uwsgi can get the env variable through `os.environ`.

but , I still can't pass the aws token validation, I think that's another issue.